# Wamp server errors on Windows 7

Tags: iis-7.5, wamp

I do not have SKYPE on my machine.

I do have the wamp 2.2E failure to start/orange icon issue.

All three of these things are happening:

1. Another application is running on port 80, which is used by wamp.
   wamp > apache > service > Test port 80
   says my port is used by Microsoft-IIS/7.5

   I can't find IIS to delete off of my program files - how do I fix this?
2. The hosts file in WINDOWS folder, if entry 127.0.0.0 localhost is commented
   have tried nine ways to sunday to uncomment and save.
   NO matter how I change my permissions (spent 2 hours on this) - will not let me save

   is this the end of my journey?  can this be overcome?
3. On the systray Wamp icon, under Apache/Service I noticed the Start&Stop&Restart 
   were grayed out with Install service available.

   clicked on Install service, a popup confirmed port 80 is being used and I'm stuck

I'm a front-end developer/designer - can anyone please help me figure out how to get wamp running?

(p.s. - even tried running older version of 2.1 - same issues as above.)

Comment: To edit the hosts file - [read this](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-hosts-file/). It worked for me.

Comment: IIS is in the list of 'Windows Features' if you do not have any IIS applications installed elsewhere, this is all I can think: http://i.imgur.com/jLkvzDc.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a different port number for WAMP: http://www.brucerick.com/changing-wamp-2-1-port-from-80-to-81-or-other-port/ or you can turn off IIS to free up port 80: http://forums.iis.net/t/1150139.aspx/1

It is very possible that you will not be able to "save" your hosts file due to permissions issues. Try saving it to a location you are allowed to save to, then copy the file into its proper place - this way you will get a UAC prompt assuming you have the privileges to answer that.

Apache cannot start on port 80 if port 80 is occupied. Fix problem one before you worry about problem three.

I know it is frustrating when WAMP will not turn green or give you a helpful error - I'm sorry it is being so difficult.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Just disabling IIS 7 did the job.